# Measuring the resistance of USB car chargers

Tags: resistance, buck, 12v

I have a few USB chargers that are powered through a 12 V car receptacle. I measured their resistance with a multimeter, applying the probes to the contacts of the 12 V input.

One of the chargers had a resistance of 1 MΩ, another one had on the order of hundreds of kΩ, and one only 1 Ω. Presumably, there is a switching DC-DC converter inside the charger, and on the average, the charger has to consume a bit more power than the power given through the USB ports.

- Is measuring the resistance of the circuit in this way useful?
- What are typical resistances of step-down converters when measured from the input side?

Comment: It's probably better to measure current and voltage on each side of converter, and do the numbers. Just a resistance measurement tells you next to nothing.

Comment: Measuring the resistance in this way is not useful at all, no.

Comment: @Hearth  you must not be a Test Engineer with my experience then if you believe that.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Well, I'm pretty clearly not, given that you've apparently been practicing since before I was born.

Comment: Then you comment is completely false @Hearth

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Would you have preferred if I said it's not useful at all outside of extremely uncommon situations? It's certainly not useful if the person doing the measurement doesn't have a good idea of what to expect out of it.

Comment: @Hearth this is exactly how ESR is related to any Vreg with load regulation error specs. Zout(f) is then ESR increased by GBW then reduced by Cout impedance.

Comment: Worse yet you have misled 4 of your followers.

Comment: Next time ask before you make false assumptions.and thus false conclusions.

Comment: You can analyze it or test it. 1% load regulation error for a 5V 50A PSU is 50 mV or deltaV/delta I =ESR of  1 mOhm. This is basic Ohm’s Law for incremental V/I or ESR at DC. Then ESR/Rmin x 100% = load Reg error where Rmin draws rated load current. But like any proportion control system Error is reduced by DC loop gain.

Comment: This means an Op Amp with 200 Ohm output impedance and 1e6 gain can have an ESR of 200 uohms with unity gain until current limiting starts >15mA or so. @Hearth . Does that make sense now!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 So, do you berate everyone who glosses over complicated and unnecessary details when talking to beginners, or do you have some grudge against me personally?

Comment: I never criticize unless to correct, No grudges, don’t take it personally.  but passive resistance shown in schematic is reduced by loop gain an can never be measured while active since ohmmeter uses an active current source., so thus is what newbies need to learn, so rather than feed pablum, I start with solids, and beware of choice of extremes like never

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is measuring the resistance of the circuit in this way useful?

No. A look at the sample schematic below shows you that the only return path between your meter probes is through IC1. This will have a complex circuit of transistors, etc., and most will require more voltage than your test meter can supply before the circuit can turn on.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 12 V USB power-supply. Source: [dmohankumar](https://dmohankumar.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/car-usb-charger-using-mc-34063-start-up-project-40/).*

> Presumably, there is a switching DC-DC converter inside the charger, and on the average, the charger has to consume a bit more power than the power given through the USB ports.

Correct, although technically it is not a charger. It is a 5 V power supply. The charging is controlled inside the phone and it will regulate the current as required to safely charge the battery.

Comment: Wrong it’s a variable V supply with a pot for feedback to boost Vref in a FB loop.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot measure resistance of any active circuit with another active circuit like a DMM resistance measurement which uses a constant current source. However you may measure voltage drop with a load Current from a load R. The R ratio of source to load will match the voltage drop ratio to source.

This is a variable voltage regulator with a pot for Vfb, so it requires you to manage CV for charging and sense current for shutdown. It is not a battery charger.  the smart USB device draws its load to regulate CC and CV then shut down but could be any voltage from 1.25 to 5V.

If the smart portable draws more than the open loop Rtotal can supply as I calc below, it will shutdown like a burp charger restarting , but if it draws less then the ESR is low as I calc. below.

\$% load regulation =Delta Vout/(Vout*Imax)\$

This is limited by the input series drop of Rin + RdsOn + DCR of L =Rtot =(Vin-Vout)*If  that saturates the switch at  max current (meaning no current linear operation of FET)

But when not saturated the error voltage is reduced by the loop gain below this limit and only considers the RdsOn +DCR= Rol for open loop with error voltage gain, Av.

Thus ESR =Rol/Av is the effective series resistance of the regulator, which also defines both the the voltage drop using Ohm’s Law.  ESR*Imax= Vdrop

The load regulation error % of any regulator is thus related to the ESR*Imax/Vout *100%

Comment: This answer needs more explanation.

Comment: @Juho They always do.

Comment: I trust you understand everything otherwise lookup or ask what you do not know .

Comment: (-1) to those who misunderstand

Comment: -4 is due to lack of user written feedback and the ratchet effects of ill will

Comment: So, is it mainly the saturation current of the switch that determines the maximum current of the regulator? What is Rin and why does it not matter below the saturation current?

Comment: Current & voltage feedback are used to regulate current pulse width and voltage with proper selections of Rsense for Feedback and Lmin and Vout, Imax thus the losses in RdsOn , DCR need to be minimized for efficiency but affect the short circuit current at fault before protection reacts.